# Can I have an editable computed-column?

Tags: sql-server-2005, calculated-columns

Is it possible to edit computed-column values?

I have a computed-col in my table, sometimes, I need to enter an individual value that is not the computed value.

Is there a way to store it in the computed col, or I have to make an additional col?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, computed columns are by design always readonly.

You need to change the underlying actual columns (that the computed column relies on) to change the computed column.

This is still the same in SQL Server 2008.

What you could do is have a regular column, and a trigger that would sometimes update that column, and sometimes skip the update.

Marc